# Spring hierarchy visibility best practice

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I am trying to understand how to best make use of spring application context hierarchies. Assuming I have an Application where I have @Controller beans, @Service beans, and @Repository beans, representing a front-end, business and persistence layer, it would seem nice if the layers had contexts in which only beans are visible which are relevant to the context. It would also be nice if I did not need special code for creating beans, just using @Autowired should be enough.

I can create a context for my repositories, let's say repoContext, in which there exist only the repository beans. The service layers needs access to those, but not vice versa, so I'd might create another context serviceContext which has repoContext as parent. Now the front-end layer needs the services, so I might create a controllerContext with serviceContext as parent. But doing so, the controllerContext would also be able to deliver repository beans to the front-end layer, which is the opposite of what I wanted.

So it seems to me that to properly separate bean dependencies in separate contexts, the parent-child relationship is not very useful to provide dependencies to a context.
Is there any better way? Could there be a front-end and a backend context sharing configuration of the service beans, but with the backend context being resposible to insatntiate service beans first (because only this context has repositories)? Or would that approach lead to the frontend context trying to instantiate own service beans?

Comment: Sounds like a lot of work to enforce a design pattern.